# Reliably tell SAML request is compressed or not?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

I'm working with integrating SSO for 3rd party authentication with Office 365(SP) and my app as the IDP.

Reading through Spec Over [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/saml-session-token/v1.0/cs01/saml-session-token-v1.0-cs01.html#__RefHeading__2194_1875771793)

It states

```
The use of compression MAY be indicated via metadata
```

But I could not find any relevant info regarding the compression in [SAML-metadata spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf)

What is the current situation?

Once's successfully implemented Office 365 we have a plan of integrating other services.

Now the point over here SAMLrequest from Microsoft is **not compressed**.

Whereas considering Google as one of the other services. The samlRequest (I vividly remember) from google was compressed.

So, is there a reliable way to tell whether the request i.e SAML request would be compressed or not? by the SP.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the common practice is:

- When a SAMLRequest is sent to your IdP using REDIRECT binding, aka GET web method, it uses DEFLATE compression.
- When a SAMLRequest is sent to your IdP using POST binding, aka POST web method, it doesn't use any compression.